# Scrolling in ActionBar title-android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I create an Actionbar title with scrolling where clicking on a particular title item moves to the corresponding page?

You can see this functionality in Google Drive app in android mobile phones:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom actionBar with a textView for the title that has:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

That should get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a library called Veni Divi that provides you with a custom action bar title that behaves like the one from Google Drive app.

In case someone needs this functionality, the source is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/mg6maciej/veni-divi).
You may see a demo app [on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.veni.divi.demo).